# Creating geometry from lat/lon in table using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a table with over 800,000 records including a lat and long column. The data source did not create geometries, so I was looking around how to do this. I know there's ST_MakePoint(x,y,SRID) but all the documentation and other threads show how to create single points. How do I create the geometry type using these columns?

Comment: do you mean create lines from these points? Because points are geometry just as lines and polygons are... So if you're looking at creating lines from these points, check this recent blog post from Paul Ramsey: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/03/making-lines-from-points.html

Comment: Nope. I meant like converting them to geometry types to be used in spatial queries. Looks like my question has been answered though so thank you!

Answer (score 75):

Newer versions of PostGIS allow the following, slightly more common, syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);
```

Then use ST_SetSrid and ST_MakePoint to populate the column:

```
UPDATE your_table SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

See documentation here:

- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html
- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html

Comment: You can also use the newer `ST_POINT(lon, lat, srid)` function. The srid parameter is optional, and you can pass this in the `ST_SetSRID` instead, like above.

Answer (score 23):

If you haven't already [add a geometry column](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#geometry_columns) (assuming EPSG:4326 here):

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('your_table','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

Then `UPDATE`, passing in the names of your x and y fields:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

This will update the entire table, unless you include a `WHERE` clause

Comment: I think ST_SRID should be ST_SetSRID. I got an error when using ST_SRID

Answer (score 3):

As a point of clarity for future users, lat / long coordinates are technically Geography (not Geometry). It is better convention to name geometry/geography database fields in accordance with the type of the object. Storing what is technically Geography in a column called 'geom' does not allow you to glance at the field and know what is actually there.

Data in lat / long are geography (i.e., geographic coordinate system) SRID: 4326

Data in a projected coordinate system like UTM, Web Mercator, State Plane, etc. are geometry (i.e., Cartesian coordinates).

Reference:
http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html

Comment: Many spatial functions accept only geometry, not geography, some accept both. Therefore I prefer to use geometry over geography.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a geom column to your table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);
   ```
2. Update the geom column using the below command

   ```
   UPDATE tableName SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude::double 
   precision, latitude::double precision), 4326);
   ```