# How to create geometry from set or array of lat/lon in table using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

My question is similar to [Creating geometry from lat/lon in table using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145007/creating-geometry-from-lat-lon-in-table-using-postgis) , but I need to convert set or array of LON & LAT in PostgreSQL into geometry value.

For example, I can convert single LON & LAT to geometry point using below code (using PostgreSQL command) :

```
SET geometry = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')',4326);
```

What if I have array of LON & LAT like this `lon1,lon2,lon3,lat1,lat2,lat3` and I want to combine those coordinates to geometry values which will produce a long polygon shape instead of a single point shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little nasty to store coordinates that way...

However, more importantly, creating actual *Polygons* from points require some pre-conditions to be met:

- vertices (i.e. your coordinate pairs) need to be in (any) winding order (there are contrary definitions of what direction that order should take between formats; PostGIS itself doesn't care)
- the last vertex needs to be identical with the first; a simple *Polygon* is usually defined as a *closed LineString*

Assuming that your arrays fulfill these conditions, running

```
UPDATE  <table> AS a
    SET <geom> = (
        SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(dmp.x, dmp.y))), <SRID>)
        FROM   <table> AS b,
               LATERAL UNNEST(<array>[:ARRAY_LENGTH(<array>, 1)/2], <array>[ARRAY_LENGTH(<array>, 1)/2+1:]) AS dmp(x, y)
        WHERE  a.<id> = b.<id>
    )
;
```

will create *Polygons* with a given `<SRID>` in column `<geom>` from your `<array>` column. If you'd rather want *LineString*s, remove the wrapping `ST_MakePolygon()` from the query.

If your arrays do not meet these requirements, please edit and update your question with details.